# Occasional ORA-12537: Network Session:End of file While communicating with External Source

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I'm not sure `External Source` is the correct phrasing, but essentially I have a view in my database that points to a table in a different database. Not always, but from time to time I get an `ORA-12537 Network Session: End of File` exception. I'm using Entity Framework, so I tried breaking it up so instead of using one massive query, it does a handful of queries to generate the final result. But this has had a mixed-to-no impact.

```
    public List<SomeDataModel> GetDataFromList(List<string> SOME_LIST_OF_STRINGS)
    {
        var retData = new List<SomeDataModel>();
        const int MAX_CHUNK_SIZE = 1000;
        var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)SOME_LIST_OF_STRINGS.Count / MAX_CHUNK_SIZE);
        var pageList = new List<List<string>>();

        for(var i = 0; i < totalPages; i++)
        {
            var chunkItems = SOME_LIST_OF_STRINGS.Skip(i * MAX_CHUNK_SIZE).Take(MAX_CHUNK_SIZE).ToList();
            pageList.Add(chunkItems);
        }


        using (var context = new SOMEContext())
        {
            foreach(var pageChunk in pageList)
            {
                var result = (from r in context.SomeEntity
                              where SOME_LIST_OF_STRINGS.Contains(r.SomeString)
                              select r).ToList();

                result.ForEach(x => retData.Add(mapper.Map<SomeDataModel>(x)));
            }

        }
        return retData;
    }
```

I'm not sure if there's a different approach to dealing with this exception or not, or if breaking up the query has any desired effect. It's probably worth noting that `SOME_LIST_OF_STRINGS` is pretty large (about 21,000 on average), so `totalPages` usually sits around 22.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, that error can be caused by an excessively large "IN" list in the SQL.  For example:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tbl
  WHERE somecol IN ( ...huge list of stuff... );
```

Enabling application or database level tracing could help reveal whether the SQL that's being constructed behind the scenes has a large IN list.

A workaround might be to INSERT "...huge list of stuff..." into a table and then use something similar to the query below in order to avoid the huge list of literals.

```
SELECT *
  FROM tbl
  WHERE somecol IN ( select stuff from sometable );
```

Reference*:
https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/More%20Applications%20and%20Technologies/2226769_1.html

*I mostly drew my conclusions from the part of this reference that's not publicly viewable.

Comment: So, I ended up doing something similar. I created a local table, and I just dump the data in there. It's relatively quicker, and I haven't run into the issue so far. Due to it being an external table I wasn't able to do any proper profiling, but this helped lead me in the right direction.